# Find function with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to find all the indexes that verifies a certain condition. Example, I want to plot the Heaviside function;

```
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(-5,5,11)
k_neg=x.find(x<0)
k_pos=x.find(x>=0)
y=np.zeros(len(x))
y(k_neg)=-1
y(k_pos)=1
```

I don't find such a function (like it exists on Matlab).

Note : my actual problem IS NOT to plot Heavyside, of corse ;)

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `np.where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Paul Panzer;

> Sounds like you are looking for `np.where`

Which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in one line with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-5,5,11)
y = ((x>=0)*2)-1
```

Comment: OP clearly states Heaviside is only a toy example. They want something more general.

Comment: I think this adapts to the given description but if you have a better idea please just post your solution!